# How to save data frames of different shapes in a panel? I'm trying to make a panel to store the datasets of all stocks in the form of a dataframe each

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, panel

[image showing the shapes of each dataframe(of each stock)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E80Xe.png)

Comment: Are you just storing the dataframes in one spot for retrieval later?

Comment: Yeah! Orelse I will have to use a loop in every function I write to get the needed data. According to the internet, I realized using Panel is the best way to filter it out in the functions instead of calling the stocks data again and again in every function.

Answer (score 1):

Using yahoo you can call multiple stocks at once. Yahoo reader will automatically load them into a multiindex dataframe for you. Stocks that weren't around at the beginning of your query will be filled in as NaN. You will get [Open, Hi, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume]

I've made up a short list of stocks for demonstration.

```
import pandas as pd
import fix_yahoo_finance as fyf
from pandas_datareader import data as web

# this is a work around for yahoo deprecation
fyf.pdr_override()

# to load multiple stocks into one dataframe
stocks = ['FB', 'AMZN', 'NFLX', 'GOOG']
data = web.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start = '2017-01-01', end='2019-01-01')

# to see results...
data.head(3)
```

To get just open and closing data on all the stocks.

```
data.loc[:,['Open', 'Close']]
```

Use pd.IndexSlice for flexible filtering.

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
data.loc[:,idx[['Open', 'Close'],['GOOG', 'FB']]]
```

For using Quandl you can use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'YOUR_QUANDL_KEY'

stocks = ['FB', 'AMZN', 'NFLX', 'GOOG']

stocks = web.DataReader(name = stocks, data_source = 'quandl', start = '2018-01-01', end = '2018-12-31', 
                access_key = 'YOUR_QUANDL_KEY')
stocks = stocks.sort_index(ascending = True)
```

Comment: My pleasure, would you mind upvoting the answer? Thanks

Comment: Tried doing that, Reputation issues don't display it publicly! Sorry.